# Define syntax for Suitescript 2.1: Fail to evaluate script after adding 'N/search' to define

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

The following script is deployed and runs correctly:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define([],

function() {
    const lineFieldLookup = [
      'custcol_sas_adapter', 'custcol_sas_body', 'custcol_sas_box', 'custcol_sas_endcap',
      'custcol_sas_lidcap', 'custcol_sas_mortrclr', 'custcol_sas_snout', 'custcol_sas_strmclr',
      'custcol_sas_topclamp', 'custcol_sas_tplate'];

      function validateLine(scriptContext) {
           const fieldValuesTable = lineFieldLookup.map((fieldId) => {
             return ({
               fieldId: fieldId,
               value: scriptContext.currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({sublistId:'item', fieldId: fieldId })
             })
           });
        console.log(fieldValuesTable)
    }

    return {
       validateLine: validateLine,
    };
});
```

However, adding `'N/search'` dependency to the script via browser 'edit' and clicking save throws an error.

Updated Code:

```
define(['N/search'],

function(search) {
  // nothing changed here
}
```

The error:

```
Fail to evaluate script: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":"","stack":[]}
```

What's preventing me from being able to add the search dependency?

Comment: I'd open a support case with NS for this.  I'm experiencing the same issue in my account and I've seen others talk about this issue in [NetSuite Professionals Slack](https://netsuiteprofessionals.slack.com/archives/C29HQS63G/p1620147170313500)

Comment: I had the same issue and this worked for me: edit script changing "2.1" to "2.0" or "2.x", add the modules you want, save script, edit script changing back to "2.1".  Not sure why; but I was glad that it did.  :)

Comment: @Martha unfortunately, that didn't work for me.

Comment: Check the answer by fullstack.studio below. The require import solved the issue for me. I'm still looking for official docs that list which modules need to be imported using require vs define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's time to learn the `N/query` ;)

As client side script you may load the `N/search` using `require`.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define([],
    function () {
        function loadSearch(callback) { require(['N/search'], search => { callback(null, search); }); }
        function pageInit(context) {
            try {
                loadSearch((error, search) => {
                    if (!error) {
                        let c_data = search.lookupFields({
                            type: search.Type.CUSTOMER,
                            id: "4390463",
                            columns: ["altname", "email", "address"]
                        });
                        console.log('c_data', c_data);
                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.error('loadSearch', e);
            }
        }
        return {
            pageInit: pageInit
        };
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for recommending the query module. However, to avoid confusion for devs looking for an answer to a question about 'N/search' module imports on 2.1 scripts, please remove 'query' from your post and I'll accept this as the answer. Also, is there documentation that specifies which modules need to be imported using `require` vs `define` in 2.1 scripts?

Comment: Hi, I removed the N/query from define ;). I don't think there is such a list (require vs define).  'require' can be used on the server side and the client side. while the module or script is available, it will load it. 'define' is used as a function to create entry point scripts and custom modules in SuiteScript 2.x. I think the N/search will be soon deprecated :).